# Iterating through primes a certain way

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Currently I am outputting all combinations of primes from a list and the product of that subset as follows:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import combinations

primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]

for r in range(1,len(primes)):
    for combo in combinations(primes,r+1):
        print combo, reduce(mul, combo)
```

Which outputs

```
(2,) 2
(3,) 3
(5,) 5
(7,) 7
(11,) 11
(2, 3) 6
(2, 5) 10
(2, 7) 14
(2, 11) 22
(3, 5) 15
(3, 7) 21
(3, 11) 33
(5, 7) 35
(5, 11) 55
(7, 11) 77
(2, 3, 5) 30
(2, 3, 7) 42
(2, 3, 11) 66
(2, 5, 7) 70
(2, 5, 11) 110
(2, 7, 11) 154
(3, 5, 7) 105
(3, 5, 11) 165
(3, 7, 11) 231
(5, 7, 11) 385
(2, 3, 5, 7) 210
(2, 3, 5, 11) 330
(2, 3, 7, 11) 462
(2, 5, 7, 11) 770
(3, 5, 7, 11) 1155
(2, 3, 5, 7, 11) 2310
```

Now let's say we're looking at the following chunk:

```
(2, 5, 7) 70
(2, 5, 11) 110
(2, 7, 11) 154
(3, 5, 7) 105
(3, 5, 11) 165
(3, 7, 11) 231
(5, 7, 11) 385
(2, 3, 5, 7) 210
(2, 3, 5, 11) 330
```

And for the sake of example, I want to iterate through all combinations where the product is <110. The first "endpoint" here occurs at (2,5,11) because the product is 110.

The problem is that if I **break** at this point, it'll think I am trying to break all length-3 tuples and move on to (2,3,5,7), thereby skipping the otherwise valid (3,5,7) which has a product <110. On the other hand, if I simply do **continue** at this point, I wind up iterating through a ton of tuples that I know will be a waste of time. If I know (2, 5, 11) is too large, then (2, 7, 11) will obviously be too large as well and I shouldn't have to evaluate it.

I'm not sure if my question is clear but is there another way to generate combinations where the order of the output is more in line with my structure?

Comment: You have to generate the combos manually if you want to be able to advance at an arbitrary time.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, lol

Comment: Is this one of the Project Euler questions? (Just out of curiosity.)

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that the `combinations` generator emits all tuples of length `r` in a particular order. You want them to come in a different order. Therefore, you need to write your own `combinations` generator.

These sorts of generators are usually written recursively: to emit all `r`-length combinations from `i` you first remove one element -- the first one -- then recursively emit all `(r-1)`-length combinations from the remainder.

Now, what you want to do is *stop* recursing as soon as the product is too large, so that you don't emit unnecessary tuples. Unfortunately, the usual way of writing such a generator doesn't let you do that, since lexicographic order is not the same as "in order of increasing product".

That means that you have to find a different way of recursing, one that increases the product of the numbers each time. A little thought should bring you to the following algorithm:

- Start at the smallest possible tuple.
- For each index of the tuple, try "bumping it up" to the next prime number. Do this only if

  - the product remains less than the limit, and
  - the tuple remains in sorted order.
- This gives you a new tuple to start at, so recurse on it.

This can be implemented as follows.

```
from operator import mul
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
primes_inorder = dict(zip(primes, primes[1:]))

def my_combinations(primes, r, N, start=None, prod=None):
    """Yield all sorted combinations of length `r`
       from the sorted list `primes`."""
    if start is None:
        start = primes[:r]
        prod = reduce(mul, start)
        if prod > N: return

    yield start

    for i, v in enumerate(start):
        next_v = primes_inorder.get(v, None)
        if next_v is None or (i+1 < r and next_v > start[i+1]):
            continue

        new_prod = prod / v * next_v
        if new_prod > N:
            continue

        new_start = start[:]
        new_start[i] = next_v
        for combination in my_combinations(primes, r, N, start=new_start, prod=new_prod):
            yield combination
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure how I would use this -- same two loops as before? It seems to output tuples that are too large when I do this.

Comment: @AOAOne I added some explanation -- does it make sense now? It seems to work for me, not that I have anything like a large data set to test it on.

Comment: And yes, it should work just like `combinations` except now you pass it `110` as well.

Comment: I call it with for combo in my_combinations(primes,r+1,110) and it's outputting things >=110

Comment: @AOAOne ah, bug: it emitted the first combination even if that was >=110. Fixed.

Comment: Still seems to be bugging. To be specific I am doing for r in range(1,len(primes)) followed by for combo in my_combinations(primes,r+1,110): then print combo, reduce(mul, combo)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10201/discussion-between-katrielalex-and-aoaone)